# How to add values to a json file in PHP using another json file?

Tags: php, json

How could I add homeworks to my subjects.json file, making always a new class with the existing datas in PHP?

Subjects json:

```
{
    "5ed7b235b31a4": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "teacher": "Mr. Blake"
    },
    "5ed7b3a5c1e57": {
        "subject": "IT",
        "teacher": "Mrs. Butler"
    }
}
```

Homework json:

```
{
    "5ed7ea74c27a1": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "hw": "page 19",
        "priority": "3",
        "deadline": "15.08.2020."
    }
    "5ed7eea8dcaf9": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "hw": "page 26",
        "priority": "5",
        "deadline": "10.06.2020."
}
```

Should look like:

```
{
    "5ed7ea74c27a1": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "teacher": "Mr. Blake"
        "hw": "page 19",
        "priority": "3",
        "deadline": "15.08.2020."
    }
    "5ed7eea8dcaf9": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "teacher": "Mr. Blake"
        "hw": "page 26",
        "priority": "5",
        "deadline": "10.06.2020."
}
```

after accessing to the json storage and cheking the input, my php append code:

```
$new_hw = [
            "subject" => $subject,
            "hw" => $hw,
            "priority" => $priority,
            "deadline" => $deadline
            ];
            $hwStorage->add($new_hw);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the keys in subjects and homework match?

Comment: no, they are from two different json files, these IDs are automatically generated

Comment: So the pairing is by..subject? What if there are multiple teachers for a subject? That can't happen?

Comment: Yes the pairing should be by subject, no there is just one teacher for a subject.

Comment: @peters So..what about my answer? Does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: I have figured out an easier way to do it, but thank you for helping me!

Comment: @peters Ok? Care to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

So the code should basically add teacher to the homework list?

```
$subjects_json = '{
    "5ed7b235b31a4": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "teacher": "Mr. Blake"
    },
    "5ed7b3a5c1e57": {
        "subject": "IT",
        "teacher": "Mrs. Butler"
    }
}';

$homework_json = '{
    "5ed7ea74c27a1": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "hw": "page 19",
        "priority": "3",
        "deadline": "15.08.2020."
    },
    "5ed7eea8dcaf9": {
        "subject": "Maths",
        "hw": "page 26",
        "priority": "5",
        "deadline": "10.06.2020."
    }
}';

$homeworks = json_decode($homework_json, true);

$subjects = [];
// "Re-key" subjects array to make it better suited for the job at hand
foreach(json_decode($subjects_json, true) as $subject) {
    $subjects[$subject['subject']] = $subject;
}

$result = [];
foreach($homeworks as $id => $homework) {
    $result[$id] = $homework + $subjects[$homework['subject']];
}

print_r($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

To start with, decode the text string in JSON format, so that we have the data in a format that we can work with. The 2nd argument to json_decode() makes it return arrays instead of objects.

Since we'll fetch data from subjects by subject, we change the index to subject instead of the id that we won't be using anyway.

And then all that's left is to iterate the homeworks list, fetch the subject data for each list item and add it :).

The result is in the $result array, which could then be encoded back to JSON, if one should so wish.